# is there any way to add outlines(bookmarks) to existed pdf in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I have few pdf files and could combine into single pdf called combined.pdf with the following code.

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.load("1.pdf")
 # one way to combine, very fast.
pdf << CombinePDF.load("2.pdf")
pdf << CombinePDF.load("3.pdf")
pdf << CombinePDF.load("4.pdf")
pdf.save "combined.pdf"
```

Now I want to add outlines to this combined.pdf.
Trying with the prawn, but no luck. Here is the code that i have tried

```
Prawn::Document.generate("full_template.pdf", :template => filename) do
  text "THis content is written on the first page of the template", :align => :center

  outline.define do
   section("Slaves", :destination => 1) do
     page :title => "Page 2", :destination => 2
     page :title => "Page 3", :destination => 3
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yutayamamoto/pdfoutline
I made a library which helps you adding an outline to a PDF file though it's not written in ruby.